# Numpy concatenate 2D arrays with 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate 4 arrays, one 1D array of shape (78427,) and 3 2D array of shape (78427, 375/81/103). Basically this are 4 arrays with features for 78427 images, in which the 1D array only has 1 value for each image.

I tried concatenating the arrays as follows:

```
>>> print X_Cscores.shape
(78427, 375)
>>> print X_Mscores.shape
(78427, 81)
>>> print X_Tscores.shape
(78427, 103)
>>> print X_Yscores.shape
(78427,)
>>> np.concatenate((X_Cscores, X_Mscores, X_Tscores, X_Yscores), axis=1)
```

This results in the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

The problem seems to be the 1D array, but I can't really see why (it also has 78427 values). I tried to transpose the 1D array before concatenating it, but that also didn't work.

Any help on what's the right method to concatenate these arrays would be appreciated!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try concatenating `X_Yscores[:, None]` (or `X_Yscores[:, np.newaxis]` as imaluengo suggests). This creates a 2D array out of a 1D array.

Example:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print A.shape
print A[:, None].shape
```

Output:

```
(3,)
(3,1)
```

Comment: Just to point out that `A[:, np.newaxis]` has the same behaviour than `A[:, None]` and can sometimes be more intuitive (actually `np.newaxis == None`).

Comment: however this is true only if both have same dimension. In most cases I am ending up with Array A having shape (8400,) and Array B having shape (8399, 21).

How do I truncate/delete the last few rows of A so that both A and B have same shapes like (8399,) and (8399, 21) . Please advise.

Comment: `np.newaxis` is intuitive but I still can't understand why `A[:, None]` works. Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: It works because ["`newaxis` is an alias for `None`"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and using `None` for indexing tells NumPy to add a dimension. So the 1D array is converted into a 2D array, which has axes 0 and 1.

Answer (score 17):

I am not sure if you want something like:

```
a = np.array( [ [1,2],[3,4] ] )
b = np.array( [ 5,6 ] )

c = a.ravel()
con = np.concatenate( (c,b ) )

array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

OR

```
np.column_stack( (a,b) )

array([[1, 2, 5],
       [3, 4, 6]])

np.row_stack( (a,b) )

array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: any thoughts on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676461/concatenate-combine-mx1-numpy-array-with-mxn-numpy-array

Comment: Interesting.   `np.vstack( (a,b) )` works just like row_stack, but `np.stack( (a,b) )` fails with "ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape", and `np.hstack( (a,b) )` fails with "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)"

Answer (score 6):

You can try this one-liner:

```
concat = numpy.hstack([a.reshape(dim,-1) for a in [Cscores, Mscores, Tscores, Yscores]])
```

The "secret" here is to reshape using the known, common dimension in one axis, and -1 for the other, and it automatically matches the size (creating a new axis if needed).

Comment: Could help here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676461/concatenate-combine-mx1-numpy-array-with-mxn-numpy-array

Comment: A generalisation: np.concatenate([a.reshape(*shape,-1) for a in my_arrays],axis=-1), where 'shape' is the shape of known dimensions except the last.