# dynamically append processed filename to output txt file

Tags: python, numpy, save

**samples** folder has a bunch of samples `a,b,c,d,e`.

while saving the final output `features_with_times` to a file, I want it to be appended with name of the file it just processed.
I approached using [Creating a new file, filename contains loop variable, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560600/creating-a-new-file-filename-contains-loop-variable-python) ,   and I did the following, but getting small error.

```
from __future__ import division

import librosa
import os
import numpy as np


test_src = 'samples/'

path_to_audios = [os.path.join(test_src, f) for f in os.listdir(test_src)]

for audio_path in path_to_audios:
    # blah ..
    # blah 

    # blah . . 
    # blah  . . 


    features_with_times= some_val 
    # np.savetxt('koo'+ str(k) + '.txt')

    print "saving mfcc features"
    np.savetxt('mfcc_flwts'+str(audio_path)+'.txt', features_with_times,newline ='\n', delimiter= '\t')
```

**ERROR** : IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mfcc_flwtssamples/abc.mp3.txt'

How to fix this ? how do _prevent the `samples/` tag from coming in between.
I know I can have `names_to_append = [f for f in os.listdir(test_src)]`
which will save the names of the files present in the sample/ folder. to a list.

How do I pass these to the `np.savetxt()` step.

Newbie question.

UPDATE: 
**I crude solution I came up with was to subtract the two strings:**

```
a = 'samples/'
b = audio_path
val = b.replace(a,'')
np.savetxt('mfcc_flwts_'+str(val)+'.txt', features_with_times,newline ='\n', delimiter= '\t')
```

Is there a better way to achieve my solution.

UPDATE : 2 :

**I am also able to save it to a folder of my choice as follows:**

```
save_destination = 'outputss/'
    np.savetxt(os.path.join(save_destination,'mfcc_flwts_'+str(val)+'.txt'), features_with_times,newline ='\n', delimiter= '\t')
```

Comment: What is your you expected filename/filepath?

Comment: if `samples` folder has audios `a` `b` `c`. after processing, 
outputs from np.savetxt should be `mfcc_flwts_a.txt`
`mfcc_flwts_b.txt`
`mfcc_flwts_c.txt`
so I'll know which was generated from which file.

Comment: one crude way to do would be two subtract two strings like:

`a = 'samples/'`
`>>> b = 'samples/aa.mp3'`
`>>> b.replace(a,'')`
`'aa.mp3'`

and pass this^ to the str() part of np.savetxt

Comment: also how do I save them to a specific path ?  right now they just get saved to the working directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `path_to_audios` contains the relative path of files in `samples/<filename>`, not just the filenames alone. One idea would be to change your loop a little, so you've got just the filenames available in the loop:

```
test_src = 'samples/'

filenames = os.listdir(test_src)
path_to_audios = [os.path.join(test_src, f) for f in filenames]

for fn, audio_path in zip(filenames, path_to_audios):
    # now you've got path and filename in parallel. If you need to discard the file ending since it's not ".txt",
    # split at the dot and take the first part only
    fn = fn.split('.')[0]

    print "saving mfcc features"
    np.savetxt('mfcc_flwts'+str(fn)+'.txt', features_with_times,newline ='\n', delimiter= '\t')
```

The last line saves your result in the working directory, and it's also an ugly way to write your filename. So we'd like to change it to...

```
    np.savetxt(
        os.path.join(your_target_path, 'mfcc_flwts{0}.txt'.format(fn)),
        features_with_times,
        newline ='\n',
        delimiter= '\t'
    )
```

Comment: you are a lifesaver!

Comment: could you please shed some light here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676461/concatenate-combine-mx1-numpy-array-with-mxn-numpy-array