# Concatenate NumPy 2D array with column (1D array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

Suppose I have a 2D NumPy array `values`. I want to add new column to it. New column should be `values[:, 19]` but lagged by one sample (first element equals to zero). It could be returned as `np.append([0], values[0:-2:1, 19])`. I tried: [Numpy concatenate 2D arrays with 1D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305069/numpy-concatenate-2d-arrays-with-1d-array)

```py
temp = np.append([0], [values[1:-2:1, 19]])
values = np.append(dataset.values, temp[:, None], axis=1)
```

but I get:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis 
must match exactly
```

I tried using `c_` too as:

```py
temp = np.append([0], [values[1:-2:1, 19]])
values = np.c_[values, temp]
```

but effect is the same. How this concatenation could be made. I think problem is in `temp` orientation - it is treated as a row instead of column, so there is an issue with dimensions. In Octave `'` (transpose operator) would do the trick. Maybe there is similiar solution in NumPy?

Anyway, thank you for you time.

Best regards,
Max

Comment: If `temp` is shape (n,) (1d), you can make a 2d 'column' with `temp[:,None]` or `temp.reshape(n,1)`.  That can then be `concatenate` with a 2d (n,m) array, on axis=1.  The key difference with Octave is that numpy arrays can be true 1d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [76]: values = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)                                                                 
In [77]: temp = np.concatenate(([0], values[1:,-1]))                                                         
In [78]: values                                                                                              
Out[78]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
In [79]: temp                                                                                                
Out[79]: array([ 0,  7, 11, 15])
```

This use of `concatenate` to make `temp` is similar to your use of `append` (which actually uses `concatenate`).

Sounds like you want to join `values` and `temp` in this way:

```
In [80]: np.concatenate((values, temp[:,None]),axis=1)                                                       
Out[80]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 15]])
```

Again I prefer using `concatenate` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the 1D array to 2D as shown. You can then use vstack or hstack with reshaping to get the final array you want as shown:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
b = np.array([[7, 8, 9]])
c = np.vstack([ele for ele in [a, b]])
print(c)
c = np.hstack([a.reshape(1,-1) for a in [a,b]]).reshape(-1,3)
print(c)
```

Either way, the output is:

```
[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]]
```

Hope I understood the question correctly